# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined 

Tags: javascript, mootools, blogger

I am trying to implement a moving photo slider that is no jQuery , it uses moo tools

I want a slider like this guy http://mahusay-fbt.blogspot.com/

So I got that piece of code that is specifically designed for blogger here [bit.ly/chXo9Q](http://bit.ly/chXo9Q)

I implemented it on my dummy blog  and it ain't working

This is the error i get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
hacktheplanets.blogspot.com/:1380 Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined

hacktheplanets.blogspot.com/:1657 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'addEvent'
```

I have no idea where I went wrong and I  need help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your packed version of mootools is not quite right. You should replace it.

Comment: does not matter what it is. mootools has not been eval-packed since 1.11 got replaced. running the old version will not work with modern browsers like FF4, IE9 etc, not to mention the bad practice of using eval or the fact that some anti-viruses block such scripts as the dean edwards packer is a common method for obfuscating malicious javascript.

Comment: oh really :( If anyone else finds out just answer here . I am closing this off

Comment: there's no answer other than: get a proper copy of mootools from www.mootools.net or re-copy/paste your version as the eval is not finishing (missing data). keep in mind that 1.12 version is still not going to work well with new browsers, you want 1.2.5+ - but that may break the old plugin as there were API changes.

Comment: Really, give it a go with a fresh mootools, it just might make your day .)