# jsFiddle code doesn't run on Aptana

Tags: javascript, mootools, slider, jsfiddle

(first of all, a disclaimer: I'm a JavaScript / MooTools newbie, so it's very likely that the solution may be a trivial miss)

With some help, I was able to put a simple slider to run properly on jsFiddle, using MooTools. It is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/wowenkho/uGcTx/

Now, I want to reproduce it on my own PC. I learn from some threads here that I have to wrap jsFiddle code. In Aptana, I've got the code like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools_v1_2.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function()
                {
                    window.addEvent('domready',function()
                    {
                        var s = new Slider(document.id("slider-1"), document.id("slider-input-1"),
                        {
                            onChange : function(step)
                            {
                                document.id("q1_r1").set('value',step);
                                document.id("value").set('html',step);
                            }           
                        });


                        window.onresize = function () {
                            //s.recalculate();
                        };

                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input name="q1_r1" id="q1_r1" type="hidden">

        <span id="value">0</span>

        <p ><div class="slider" id="slider-1" tabIndex="1">
            <input class="slider-input" id="slider-input-1" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I do know that the MooTools version I'm using isn't exactly the same (jsFiddle is using 1.2.5, I'm using 1.2.1). I could try to use 1.2.5 here (and I will, meanwhile), but that's not the purpose, since I have to use 1.2.1. I also do know MooTools is running well, at least theoretically, since I've made the "hello world" before and it worked.

How this is at the moment, I only see the span and a text box, instead of the slider.

I guess I'm missing something trivial here.

Thanks all possible help in advance,
Jaff

Comment: document.id was from 1.2.3 iirc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your implementation the first is simple take it out of the $function wrapper if you look in the console your domready function is not getting called.

```
                window.addEvent('domready',function()
                {
                    var s = new Slider(document.id("slider-1"), document.id("slider-input-1"),
                    {
                        onChange : function(step)
                        {
                            document.id("q1_r1").set('value',step);
                            document.id("value").set('html',step);
                        }           
                    });


                    window.onresize = function () {
                        //s.recalculate();
                    };

                });
```

The second is that you are actually using a plugin for mootools. If you look at your js fiddle it says using mootools more 1.2.5.1. It's inside the more part that you find the slider class. If you don't have that then slider is not defined. So make sure when you download the core mootools which is required for all plugins that you also check the more and slider boxes. On the mootools website when you go to 1.2.5 download for core go to the more builder and you can add those.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, @ryan! I've removed the wrapper and downloaded the two .js libraries. Still, the behaviour hasn't changed.

Code:
`  <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2.5-core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2.5.1-more.js"></script>`

Comment: yea I had to actually copy the code from mootools-1.2.5.1-more into the core file after I did that everything worked. just paste it at the bottom of the file.

Comment: "While trying to debug this, it came to me that the oroblem might be in HTML... is this true?"

(this comment was made before I saw your answer... I'll try that, thanks!)

Comment: Thanks again, @ryan! I copied "mootools-1.2.5.1-more.js" into the bottom of "mootools-1.2.5-core.js" and the behaviour is still the same. I tried with the 2 includes and also only with the core, it didn't change. Weird stuff...

Comment: what browser are you working in? if your in chrome you can right click and inspect the page and open up the console. there it will show you any errors that are occurring in the javascript.

Comment: so all the boxes I checked in the more builder were: More, Class.Binds, Element.Measure, Fx.Slide, Drag, Slider, and I didn't compress it. I then copied the whole more file and dropped it at the bottom of the core file because I was getting an error that mootools was undefined. after that it worked exactly like your jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok, I was missing Fx.Slide, and I used it compressed. In what concerns the console, it does give this error, still after downloading the more file again and append it to the core one:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined
slider_moo.html:6Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'addEvent'**

Regarding that error, I'm viewing this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275515/javascript-uncaught-referenceerror-class-is-not-defined

I'll have to leave now, but tomorrow I'll stay tuned on this. Thanks for all, mate!

Comment: This is weird as hell. Even after looking at the other thread, nothing changed (error & behaviour). I've checked in jsFiddle that the code works with MooTools 1.4.5 & MooTools 1.4.5 (compat). So, I downloaded and imported MooTools 1.4.5 and MooTools 1.4.5 with the "Include Compatibility" option. The same with the "more" part. I pasted them into the bottom of the core file, as seen before.

I must confess I don't know what to do now. Just a remaining question: concerning the core file, you just checked the "Core" option, uncompressed, @ryan? That's what I've done, maybe I've missed something...

Comment: Ok, finally I kind of solved it. I tested so many versions and combinations with no success, that I come to a brute-force attack: I chose all the options in the "core" and in the "more" parts. This worked out, both for versions 1.4.5 (core) with 1.4.0.1 (more) and 1.2.5 (core) with 1.2.5.1 (more). I also chose "No Compression", always.

Of course I'm importing many, many things I'm not using, but since I can't locate which components are indeed needed, it is the easiest way.

Thanks for all!

Comment: Glad you got it solved. If you want I can send you the file that I created from mootools that got it working on my computer, but up to you. Also as it says on the mootools site always choose uncompressed when you are developing, with -any- framework or plugin so that you can go into the code if needed and see whats actually happening. Good luck. P.S. if an answer helps solve your question make sure to mark it as the correct answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, @ryan. In what concerns the .js file you can send me that, but what I really wanted to know was the key components to make it work. It's strange because I've previously chosen the six components you mentioned, plus the core one, but who knows. Maybe I will work on finding that later, when I have time :]